# Musik site Problem with showing icons and lover opacity with :hover

Tags: css

We try to give the icons a `display: none` as default and the that they should be `display: flex` on `:hover`. We also have the cover image to have `opacity: 0.7` on hover. We can't make it work at the same time.

```
<div className="album-container">
    <div className="image-container">
        <img className="albumcover" src={props.image} alt="Album cover"    />
        <div className="icon-container hidden">
            <img className="heart-icon" src="/icons/heart.svg" />
            <img className="play-icon" src="/icons/play.svg" />
            <img className="dots-icon" src="/icons/dots.svg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would help us if you posted your CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im right you want them all to change state on hover simultaneously?

If that is the case try putting :hover selector on parent.

By the way - changing display attribute may mess with positioning which might look bad especially if there is a transition. Try animating opacity or visibility if any issues with positioning appear.

Comment: Thank you! I also saw that part of my code got missing in my question.